# ValidationError: User validation failed, Cast to String failed for value

Tags: passport.js, spotify

```
} else {
                var user = req.user; // pull the user out of the session

                user.spotify.id = profile;
                user.spotify.accessToken = accessToken;
                user.spotify.refreshToken = refreshToken;

                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }
```

The code for saving the info

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ValidationError: User validation failed: spotify.id: Cast to String failed for value "
```

Using passport-spotify, I am receiving all the info about the account, but then the program crashes. I am honestly not sure what this is, as I've wracked my brain all day and seen many pages of google.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turned out to be a mongoose schema issue. Spotify was trying to send one VERY large json, so instead of simulating that with a schema I just made an array in the schema and it stored it all in there. Over-engineering strikes again!